# Revert all files in a Google Drive directory to old version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

A virus recently encrypted all my files and unfortunately google back up and sync immediately  uploaded the new versions of the files (encrypted) to my drive.
I know I can restore a single file to a previous version but I have roughly 30,000 files on my drive - meaning I can't restore all of these files manually...
I tried working with Apps Script but I couldn't really find a way to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/42402713/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42403970/1595451

Comment: Thanks you soo much for your help! the first link was extremely helpful! I'm writing a code that fixes all my files now (so far I've managed to use the code to fix some files but I'm extending it now) and I'll upload the code here once I'm done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the help by Ruben I used the code suggested in  [CryptoLocker - restore Drive file version with Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42402713/1595451) (minor changes - my code runs through all files in the folder including subfolders) to delete all versions of my files that were made at the day of the virus attack. Now the version of each file is what it was before the virus attack.

```
/** A function that delete all version of files in folder and subfolders that were made at the day of the virus attack and afterwards*/
function fixAllFilesInFolder(){ 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folderId = #enter folder Id here
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // I change the folder ID  here 
  handleFolder(folder, 0)   
}

/** A recursive function - delete all 'bad' versions of files in folder and calls itself with each of the subfolders to do the same*/
function handleFolder(folder, treeRank){
  Logger.log(String(treeRank) + ': ' + folder.getName());
  fixFolderFiles(folder)
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders(); 
  while (subFolders.hasNext()){
    subFolder = subFolders.next();
    handleFolder(subFolder, treeRank + 1)
  }

}

/** Delete all 'bad' versions of files in folder*/
function fixFolderFiles(folder){
  var files = folder.getFiles(); 
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    deleteRevisions(file)
  }
}

/** Delete 'bad' version of a file*/
function deleteRevisions(file){  
  var fileId = file.getId();  
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var virusDate = new Date(2021, 3, 30) /** Put your attack date here!*/
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 1) 
    {    
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) 
      {
        if (i > 0){
          var revision = revisions.items[i];      
          var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
          if(date.getTime() > virusDate.getTime()){
            return Drive.Revisions.remove(fileId, revision.id); 
          }
        }       
      }  
    }
  
  }
```

Two notes:

1. Unfortunately Apps Script can only run for ~5 minutes at a time, so I had to run the code multiple times (tens of times) from different folders to get to all my files.
2. Even after you revert the files to their previous version, the name of my files still ended with the encryption format '.wrui'. To fix it I downloaded all the files and ran a python script (probably could be done in Apps Script but I feel more comfortable with python) that change all the name.

```py
from os import rename, listdir, walk
from os.path import join, isfile

ENCRYPTION = 'wrui' #Here should be the encryption format

#A function to rename a file without the encryption format - it makes sure that no file is named with the same name exactly. In that case, it adds '2' to the files name
def renameFile(address, origin_name, new_name):
    final_name = new_name
    
    if isfile(join(address, new_name)):
        name_list = new_name.split('.')
        name_list[-2] += '2'
        final_name = '.'.join(name_list)
        
    rename(join(address, origin_name), join(address, final_name))

#A function to rename all files in a specific folder
def purifyFolderFiles(folder_address):
    for file in listdir(folder_address):
        f_list = file.split('.')
        if len(f_list) > 1:
            if f_list[-1] == ENCRYPTION:
                renameFile(folder_address, file, '.'.join(f_list[:-1]))
                
            elif f_list[-2] == ENCRYPTION:
                if f_list[-3] == f_list[-1]:
                    renameFile(folder_address, file, '.'.join(f_list[:-2]))                
                else:
                    del f_list[-2]
                    renameFile(folder_address, file, '.'.join(f_list))

#This next few lines iterate through all the subfolders of the specific folder you put and use purifyFolderFiles to rename every file there
folder = #enter you folder address here
for path, subdirs, files in walk(folder):
    for name in subdirs:
        subdir_address = join(path, name)
        purifyFolderFiles(subdir_address)
```

Comment: 1.  Thank you, this is amazing. 2.  Not sure what to put here? var folderId = #enter folder Id here. I thought this was the name of the file but not sure what the corresponding id would be.

Comment: OK, me = dummy. Anyways, I used the folder ID from the URL to Execute this but I run into "Attempted to execute fixAllFilesInFolder, but could not save."

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer since I cannot comment.

A few things I learned while attempting the accepted answer.

1. The date you enter into new Date(Year, Month, Day), needs to be correctly formatted. The main issue is that the month values range from 0 (January) to 11 (December) not 1-12.
2. In your coding area you need to add the service "Drive". To do this press the plus button in the library section, find the Drive service, and add it. Then grant the required permissions.
   [image]
3. The folder ID is the link in your browser and not the name of the folder itself.
   [image]

That was all I needed to do to make it work.
If you'd like the program to tell you which files it is changing, replace the deleteRevisions function with this code:

```
/** Delete 'bad' version of a file*/
function deleteRevisions(file){  
  var fileId = file.getId();  
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var virusDate = new Date(2021, 09, 05) /** Put your attack date here! Year, Month (0-11), Day*/
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 1) 
    {
    Logger.log(file);    
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) 
      {
        if (i > 0){
          var revision = revisions.items[i];      
          var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
          if(date.getTime() > virusDate.getTime()){
            return Drive.Revisions.remove(fileId, revision.id); 
          }
        }       
      }  
    }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made some slight changes in order to fix Original File Name and Modified Time in order to recovered file stays as was before infection.

```html
/** Delete 'bad' version of a file*/
function deleteRevisions(file) {
  Logger.log(file);
  var fileId = file.getId();
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var virusDate = new Date("2022-08-03"); /** Date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format*/
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) { // rev[0] (v1) is original file version
        var revision = revisions.items[i];
        var revDate = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
        if (revDate.getTime() > virusDate.getTime()) {
          Logger.log("Gonna delete " + file + " v." + i + "-" + revDate.toISOString());
          //return Drive.Revisions.remove(fileId, revision.id);
          Drive.Revisions.remove(fileId, revision.id);
          fixFileNameAndModifiedDate(file);

        }
      }
    }
  } else {

    fixFileNameAndModifiedDate(file);

  }
}


/** Fix 'correct' File Name & Last modified Date  */
function fixFileNameAndModifiedDate(file) {

  var fileId = file.getId();
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var lastFileVNr = revisions.items.length - 1; // Last File Version Number
  var lastFileVIt = revisions.items[lastFileVNr];  // Last File Version Item
  var lastFileVDt = new Date(lastFileVIt.modifiedDate); //Last File Version Date
  var lastFileVNm = lastFileVIt.originalFilename; //Last File Version Name
  var currFileMDt = file.getLastUpdated(); // Current File Modified Date
  var currFileMNm = file.getName(); // Current File Name .getName()

  // Different Modified Dates
  if (lastFileVDt.getTime() !== currFileMDt.getTime()) {

    Logger.log("Gonna change modif date: " + lastFileVDt.toISOString())

    Drive.Files.patch({ modifiedDate: lastFileVDt.toISOString() },
      fileId,
      { modifiedDateBehavior: "fromBody", supportsAllDrives: true });

  }

  // Different File Name
  if (lastFileVNm !== currFileMNm) {

    Logger.log("Gonna change file name: " + lastFileVNm)

    Drive.Files.patch({ title: lastFileVNm },
      fileId,
      { supportsAllDrives: true });

  }

  return

}
```